# Connect Infrared sensor with GPIO

Tags: gpio, pi-4, sensor

I'm following a tutorial on how to connect an infrared sensor to the raspberry pi to control it with remote control. So far so good, the infrared sensor is working, but now I have to read its output with the GPIOs. However, the tutorial I'm following is for another model of rpi (I have a 4GB pi4 model), and they are saying to connect the output of the sensor to the GPIO 18 (rpi 12) pin.

I don't want to burn any pin, so can someone help me choosing the right pin please?

Basically, in the tutorial, they are using this command: `mode2 -d / dev / lirc0`  and getting these results:
[image]

Here is their setup:
[image]

I'd like to get something similar, so I can then get what is the infrared input through some python script. Thanks for your help!

The article is in french, but [here it is](https://www.raspberryme.com/raspberry-pis-telecommandes-et-recepteurs-ir/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pin outs on all the Pi's with the 40-pin header are the same.

See https://pinout.xyz/

GPIO 18 is still connected to pin 12.

Your green jumper wire is connected to GPIO 18 (pin 12).

Comment: You pretty much answered my question, however, I discovered that we can modify the IR input pins, and in my distribution of raspbian they were set to gpio17. You couldn't guess it with the info I provided, so I'm accepting this answer.